# How to keep a "referrer" attribute through all the links of a website?

Tags: php, html, url, attributes, referrer

Some of my visitors arrive on my website with a "partner referrer" attribute in their URL, like this one:

> https://example.com/index.php?referrer=mypartner

I would like to keep this attribute throughout their visit, and even insert it into the Google PlayStore URL if they click the "Download" button.

Is there a way to automatically forward the attribute "referrer" (if it exists) through all the links of a website? Or do I have to do it manually in PHP?

```
$referrer = $_GET['referrer'];
```

Comment: Do you really need to store the `referrer` state in the get parameters of each endpoint, or could you store that information in the session? You could then apply it to external URLs as needed, such as your links to the Google Play Store.

Comment: You are right! I only need to store it in the session. Thx! I'm getting tired, I need a break :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the referrer in the session and then apply it to external URLs as needed. Otherwise, you'll need to manually add it to each URL, which would be tedious.